# where are the objects of 'class' definitions in ES6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

An ES6 class is a 'syntactic sugar' around the wellknown object-prototype based OOP, AFAIK. Therefore I'd expected to find class definitions in `window` just before tried this in a browser:

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.fooFunction = function() {};

class Bar {
    barFunction(){}
}

console.log(window.Foo); // shows: function Foo() ...
console.log(window.Bar); // shows: undefined !!!
```

The latter shows `undefined` instead of `function Bar()...`

Where is the Bar object/function that represents the Bar class?

Comment: It's the same for `let`/`const` - that `var` variables (or functions) in the global scope get added to the global object is... a debatable legacy thing.

Comment: `console.log(Bar)`

Comment: Related: [why don't const and let statements get defined on the window object](/q/55030498/4642212).